# Leaflet Draw: differentiating between multiple controls

Tags: leaflet

I'm adding two instances of Leaflet Draw (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) like this (only using lines):

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        polygon: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: false
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

var drawControl2 = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        polygon: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: false
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl2);
```

Now I want to listen to the `draw:drawvertex` event and do different things depending on if I had activated the `drawControl` or `drawControl2`:

```
map.on('draw:drawvertex', function (e) {
    console.log("Vertex drawn", e);
});
```

How can I differentiate which drawControl is currently active?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dirty way to know which drawControl is active.

The trick is to put them in different map corners. It helps to check which `ul.leaflet-draw-actions` is visible when the user draws. The one in `div.leaflet-top` or the one in `div.leaflet-bottom` for example :

```
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'topleft',
    draw: {
        polygon: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: false
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);

var drawControl2 = new L.Control.Draw({
    position: 'bottomleft',
    draw: {
        polygon: false,
        rectangle: false,
        circle: false,
        marker: false
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl2);

map.on('draw:drawvertex', function (e) {
    console.log("Vertex drawn", e);
    if ($('div.leaflet-top ul.leaflet-draw-actions').is(':visible')){
        console.log('it was drawn with drawControl');
    }
    else {
        console.log('it was drawn with drawControl2 !');
    }
});
```

It's dirty but it works.